# XGboost classifier

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to XGBoost and I am currently working on a project where we have built an XGBoost classifier. Now we want to run some feature selection techniques. Is backward elimination method a good idea for this? I have used it in regression but I am not sure if/how to use it in a classification problem. Any leads will be greatly appreciated.

Note: I have already tried permutation line importance and it has yielded good results! Looking for another method to evaluate the features in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Consider asking your question on Cross Validated since feature selection is more about theory/practice than code.

What is your concern ? Remove "noisy" features who drive down your results, obtain a sparse model ? Backward selection is one way to do of course. That being said, not sure if you are aware of this but XGBoost computes its own "variable importance" values.

```
# plot feature importance using built-in function
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from xgboost import plot_importance
from matplotlib import pyplot
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)
# plot feature importance
plot_importance(model)
pyplot.show()
```

Something like this. This importance is based on how many times a feature is used to make a split. You can then define for instance a threshold below which you do not keep the variables. However do not forget that :

- This variable importance has been obtained on the training data only
- The removal of a variable with high importance may not affect your prediction error, e.g. if it is correlated with another highly important variable. Other tricks such as this one may exist.

Comment: Hi, I did get feature importance previously, but I was trying to know if backward elimination is a valid option for checking feature strength like in regression? If so, how would the code look like?